# Check if result is unique

Tags: java, regex

I would like to extract a number 3-5 length from a text. The pattern below works for all my cases.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^|[\\D]|.*[\\D])(?<number>[0-9]{3,5})($|[\\D]|[\\D].*)");

    //Working examples always returns 111
    //Matcher m = pattern.matcher("XX 111, YYY 37124091");
    //Matcher m = pattern.matcher("XX 111");
    //Matcher m = pattern.matcher("X111");
    //Matcher m = pattern.matcher("111");
```

The only problem I got is when the pattern, as I believe, should find several matches as from the example below (111, 123) instead it only returns 123

```
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher("XX 111, CCC 123 YYY 37124091");

    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group("number");
    }
```

How can I identify that the pattern did match 2 times, or why isnt it matching for 111 and 123?

Comment: Are you using Java 7 ?

Comment: @sln yes do use latest 1.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only problem I got is when the pattern, as I believe, should find several matches as from the example below (111, 123) instead it only returns 123

You need to make `*` quantifier reluctant instead of greedy.

For your data

```
XX 111, CCC 123 YYY 37124091
```

`.*\\D` part will be able to match

```
"XX 111, CCC "  
 ^---------^^
      |     |
     .*    \\D
```

consuming `111`.

Try changing

```
Pattern.compile("(^|\\D|.*\\D)(?<number>[0-9]{3,5})($|\\D|\\D.*)");
```

to

```
Pattern.compile("(^|\\D|.*?\\D)(?<number>[0-9]{3,5})($|\\D|\\D.*?)");
//add these               ^                                     ^
```

Also `\\D` is itself character class so you don't need to surround it with `[..]`. In other words you don't need to write it as `[\\D]`, simple `\\D` is enough.

---

> How can I identify that the pattern did match 2 times

Regex will not remember all previously matched results. If you want to get only unique values then store them in Set.

Answer (score 3):

Just change it to a lazy quantifier.

```
 # "(^|[\\D]|.*?[\\D])(?<number>[0-9]{3,5})($|[\\D])"

 (                                  # (1 start)
      ^ 
   |  [\D] 
   |  .*? [\D] 
 )                                  # (1 end)
 (?<number>                         # (2 start)
      [0-9]{3,5} 
 )                                  # (2 end)
 (                                  # (3 start)
      $ 
   |  [\D] 
 )                                  # (3 end)
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 7 ) 
XX 111,  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 3 ) 
XX   
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 3 , len 3 ) 
111  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 6 , len 1 ) 
,  

-----------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 7 , len 9 ) 
 CCC 123   
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 7 , len 5 ) 
 CCC   
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 12 , len 3 ) 
123  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 15 , len 1 )
```

Answer (score -1):

For identifying numbers of three to five digits, you want to use something like this `\b[1-9]\d{2,4}\b`

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but could be a useful comment.